# Is it incorrect to say, "You say you will if you could but you can't"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, lyrics

Sorry for my bad English.

I was listening the music Seaside Rendezvous from the Queen and in this song Freddie Mercury sings this phrase, but the correct way to write wouldn't be "You say you will if you could but you can't"?

Comment: Better would be, “You say you ***would*** if you could, but you can’t.”

Comment: Or “You say you will if you ***can***, but you can’t.”

Comment: The band's name is "Queen," not "the Queen" ... and songwriters have something known as *poetic license*, which means they ain't gotta follow no grammar rules nohow. So there ain't no "correct" way to write a song.

Comment: As these are lyrics from a song, then poetic licence applies.
Virtually any order of words are correct! Re-compose: "How can I comply when.....(excuse)!

Comment: Robusto, thanks for the feedback. I know about poetic license, but right know I'm studying English and I need simple explanations to understand how to write grammatically correct phrases.  :)

Comment: Well, rock songs wouldn't be a good place to look for studying "correct" English.

Comment: I understand your perspective, but I strongly disagree. Music is a excellent way to improve the pronunciation skills and learn new words.

Answer (score 1):

> You say you will if you could but you can't

This is a strange kind of reported speech: if we think about what was actually said and add some quotation marks, it might be:

> You say "I will if I can", but you can't - *the second person will try to do it*
>   You say "I would if I could, but I can't" - *the second person will not even try to do it, because they don't think they can*

So, there are two possible correct options for the strange-reported-speech version:

> You say you will if you can, but you can't.
>   You say you would if you could, but you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more proper:

> "You'd say you would if you could, but you can't."

It goes to show that in lyrics and poetry, grammar goes right out the window...

Comment: I was analyzing the sentence and a question came to me. Is it correct use "you'd" in this situation? and why? "you'd" does not mean you would? Thank you.

Comment: *You'd* changes the meaning. It is a contraction of *You would say*, and the sentence then means: *If you were able to say "you would", then you would say that, but you can't.* That is not what the original sentence intends, and the first world should be *You*.